# Where should interfaces go in C# layered app

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

I'm building a C# WPF app that will use IBM iSeries data for starters but will use oracle data via web service later. In order to switch between them (and support testing) we create interfaces and program the view to  interface, right? Each of the data sources would be responsible for mapping to a common DTO structure used in the view model.
So if these two data sources that implement the interfaces are in separate projects, where are the interfaces defined? I'm thinking about how to define the interfaces so I don't have to keep up separate versions in the respective data source projects. If I create the interfaces in the view then it would create circular reference, the data source needing the view for the interfaces and the view needing the data source for dependency injection.
Please forgive me for the rather generic question. I'm not asking "how do I structure my app", it's more of how do I solve the specific issue of the mechanics of the interfaces.

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a separate project. Add a reference to that project wherever you want to use them.